# BaseExpandableListAdapter with ExpandableListView returns the wrong child view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have BaseExpandableListAdapter with ExpandableListView but I'm having trouble getting my child ViewHolder initialized to the right view. I put a break point in getChildView and the first time it is called everything is fine

groupPosition:0, childPosition:0, convertView:null

The ViewHolder gets set and we are good for the first row (0). The next time it gets called I get:

groupPosition:0, childPosition:1, convertView:ViewHolder object from row (0)

Why is it returning the view from row 0? I've included the methods I'm overriding from BaseExpandableListAdapter. Is there another method(s) I need to override in order to get the right view?

```
child_layout.xml
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="9">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText.../>
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>




// Group and children are both collections
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return group.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return group.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return group.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return group.get(groupPosition).getChildren().toArray()[childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return getGroup(groupPosition).hashCode();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
    if( null == convertView ) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate(R.layout.group_layout, parent, false);
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        // add delete group button
    } else {
        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (null == v){
        v = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate(child_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        // bind edittext fields
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: remove your if and else and put this ..if (convertView == null) {
             LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
         }

Answer (score 2):

My page layout contained a vertical LinearLayout that wrapped everything. I had layout_height="wrap_content". Changing this to match_parent fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey, you are awesome. This is so silly in Android how inconsistent child position is if your expandable list view is wrap content... It was REALLY throwing off my data/views. I almost just used group position and pulled all children and created layouts for each all in one shot (child count only set to 1). Thank you sir!

Comment: Glad I could help!